# OctoberCMS form validation alert issue

Tags: forms, validation, octobercms

I have installed a fresh copy of OctoberCMS, added Users plugin, and created theme. Everything is fresh and no plugin modifications made. Now I created registration page and testing it. It appears that form validation works a bit funny. I leave all fields empty and click on submit button.

It throws alert box like this, which is a bit unexpected.

[image: Alert]

Then if i click submit button a second time form validation shows field errors - as it normally would be. I only wannt this kind of alerts without an popup box..

[image: Field alert]

Anyone has idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

The javascript alert `name field is required` is thrown by the AJAX framework of OctoberCMS because you submitted a form which did not pass the Model's validation rules.

Check your User Model and you may notice that the `name` field is required.

```
public $rules = [ 'name' => 'required' ]; // no name was supplied
```

Here you have two options ;

- Validate form data before submission using JS

  ```
      $('button.submit').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault(); // prevent submission

      // check Form fields are valid

        // then Submit form using the AJAX API - OnCreateUser

          $.request('onCreateUser', {
          data: {name : ..., surname: ....}, // Data Object
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
              // handle errors..
            }
          });
      });
  ```
- Use Global AJAX handlers for ur site - the popup won't show up but you will need to handle these events and alert the user

  ```
      $window.on('ajaxErrorMessage', function(event, message){
          //   ....
          event.preventDefault();
      });
      $window.on('ajaxError', function(event, context, status,jqXHR ){
          //   ....
          event.preventDefault();
      });
  ```

Also it is recommended you use the [validator](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/validation) class in your component and check the submitted data - You can also add custom validation rules / messages

```
  public function onCreateUser()
    {
        if (Request::ajax()) {

            $customMessages = [
             'name.required' => 'Name Field is required',
             'email.required' => 'Email field is required',
          ];

          $customAttributes = [
            'email' => 'Email',
            'name' => 'Name',
          ];

            $data = post();
            $rules['name']  = 'required';
            $rules['email'] = 'required';


            $validation = Validator::make($data, $rules,$customMessages, $customAttributes);
            if ($validation->fails()) {
                $messages = json_encode($validation->messages(), true);
                throw new ValidationException(array(
                    'title' => 'Error Creating User',
                    'message' => $messages
                ));
            }   

           ..........

        } 
    }
```